# How to obtain the top N max values of a total of products in a facts table

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a typical star schema to emulate a real, but simple, DW. My fact tables is SALES and it has, besides other products, some attributes like amount_sold, quantity_sold (per product), unit price, etc.

Now I need to introduce some data in Weka to do a Data Mining Study in which I want to characterize the people that buy the top 3 products. So, I need, perhaps a aux table that has all the distinct products in sales and the total_quantity sold for each one of them.

AUX_TOTAL_PROD_SOLD would be something like this:

```
Collumn_1= prod_id
Collumn_2= total_sold
```

So, for this purpose, I need:
**1- a PL/SQL procedure to fill my aux_Table

2- obtain the 3(or another number) most sold products**

I just need to find them and then I can relate each prod_id with the client who bought it.

Do you think it's a complicated way to do this or do you think or have a better idea?

I'm testing it, but if you can I would appreciate some code/pseudo-code.

Thank you in advance

That's how I was able to achieve this:

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT prod_ID, SUM(s_quantity_sold) as TOTAL_SOLD
FROM SALES 
GROUP BY prod_ID
ORDER BY SUM(s_quantity_sold) DESC )
where ROWNUM <=3
```

it works like a charm :)

Comment: If you found out an answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer. Remember that StackOverflow suits your immediate need, but also also suits users who will come across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Product_ID, SUM(quantity_sold) AS total_sold
FROM [SALES]
GROUP BY Product_ID
ORDER BY SUM(quantity_sold) DESC
```

or for SQL Server

```
DECLARE @n int

SET @n  = 3

SELECT TOP (@n) Product_ID, SUM(quantity_sold) AS total_sold
FROM [SALES]
GROUP BY Product_ID
ORDER BY SUM(quantity_sold) DESC
```

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't support the `TOP` keyword. I believe that the current method would use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` functions. Earlier versions of Oracle would use the `rownum` feature.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Oracle and I wasn't able to perform queries with the TOP keyword, indeed. I'm gonna try the other way around. Thank you